# Efficient eigen-decomposition of a real matrix with all real eigenvalues

Tags: similarity

I'm optimising a radar algorithm that results in real matrices which are not symmetric but which are guaranteed to have real eigenvalues. Each matrix is therefore similar to a symmetric matrix. I am solving for the eigenvalues using the LAPACK general real eigensolver SGEEV which produces the correct eigenvalues with zero imaginary component within numerical accuracy. This is obviously inefficient. What I want to do is apply a similarity transformation to these special real matrices to reduce them to symmetric form (or tri-diagonal symmetric) and then call a symmetric eigensolver. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Sometimes one arrives at this situation from constructing an isomorphism from a high-dimensional matrix algebra with symmetric generators to a low-dimensional one. Is it your setting by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

[On computation of real eigenvalues of matrices via the Adomian decomposition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260427873_On_computation_of_real_eigenvalues_of_matrices_via_the_Adomian_decomposition)

> A new approach based on the Adomian decomposition method and the
>   Faddeev-Leverrier’s algorithm is presented for finding real
>   eigenvalues of any desired real matrices. The method features accuracy
>   and simplicity. In contrast to many previous techniques which merely
>   afford one specific eigenvalue of a matrix, the method has the
>   potential to provide all real eigenvalues. Also, the method does not
>   require any initial guesses in its starting point unlike most of
>   iterative techniques.